# To put dog on the leash

Tags: phrases

Is there difference between the phrases: "To put dog on the leash" and "To put leash on the dog". Are they both valid English sentences?

Comment: "Leash" is also a verb, so you could say "To leash the dog".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "To put dog on the leash" and "To put leash on the dog".

Neither is correct because you need another article, e.g.

1. "To put **a** leash on the dog".
2. "To put **the** dog on a leash"

Now the sentences are correct. They both effectively mean the same - in both case the dog ends up with a leash around its neck.

I would say that the difference is that we have two different meanings of 'on'.

> 7 used for saying that you are wearing a piece of clothing, jewellery
>   etc, or for saying which part of your body it covers
>
> 20 used for saying who or what is affected by something
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on)

In the first case the dog is wearing the leash. In the second case the dog is controlled/affected by the leash.

Comment: I suppose if you kill the dog, grind it up into a kind of dog paste, and smear some of that onto the leash, you would very literally be _putting dog on the leash_. But as readings go, that’s a bit of a stretch (and needlessly gory, too).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - True. Also, if you prefer 'lead' to 'leash',  you could put Pb on the dog (presumably to kill fleas (?).  That would be putting lead on the dog.  ;-)

Comment: Very true! (I first read _Pb_ as shorthand for _peanut butter_ and instantly began to wonder if peanut butter had pulicidal properties…)

Comment: This accepted answer is right, but it is not correct. The phrases are correct, but they are not right. The problem (with the phrases) is semantic--the (obviously) intended meaning is not the meaning conveyed--not grammatic. Nouns name the idea of the thing as well as the thing. They are defined noumenally as well as phenomenally. Rub the dog with the leash, or mutter incantations over them, and you can say, grammatically, that you've 'put dog on the leash' or vice versa. @JanusBahsJacquet was on the right track in the comments: without the article, what's designated is the 'essence' of dog.